# how to get user input from jquery ui dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, input, modal-dialog

I've got this English language page, in which the user has to enter an English phrase into a form. The form is in a modal dialog which is evoked by clicking on an icon. Everything works up to the point of displaying the form in the dialog, but I don't know how to access the user input which will be checked against a regular expression.  Here is the jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var englishTextId = "";
  var t2e_dlog =  jQuery("div#t2e_dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      position: "center",
      resizable: false,
      draggable: false,
      dialogClass: "t2e_dlog",
      height: 140,
      width: 380,
      create: function() {                                 
          jQuery(this).parents(".ui-dialog")
         .css("border", "solid black 1px")                            
          .css("background", "#ece6ff")
          .css("border-radius", "4px")            
          .find(".ui-dialog-content")
          .css("font-family", "verdana")
          .css("font-size", "0.65em")
          .css("font-style", "normal")
          .css("color",   "#1901B2")
          .css("padding", "1px")
          .find(".ui-dialog-header")
          .css("display","none");       
      }
  });

  jQuery("span.t2e_icon").on("click", function(evnt) { 
     t2e_dlog.dialog("open");
     evnt.stopPropagation();
    var elementId = evnt.target.id;
     englishTextId = ("span#t1ee" + elementId.substring(7));
     regexId = ("regex" + elementId.substring(7));
     // to obscure text associated with the dialog box
     jQuery(englishTextId).css({"border-radius" : "3px","background" : "blue", "color" : "blue"});
   });  

   jQuery(function() {
      jQuery( "div#t2e_dialog" ).dialog({dialogClass: 't2e_dialog_style1'});
      // removes the dialog box title bar   
      jQuery("#ui-dialog-title-dialog").hide();
      jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar").removeClass('ui-widget-header');
      var input ='<div id="t2e_modal"><p>Please enter the English text here</p><form id="t2e_form" action="#"><input type="text" id="t2e_w" name="t2e_w" size=50><input id="t2e_submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit"></form></div>';
      jQuery("div#t2e_dialog").append(input);
  }); 

  // unobscures the text         
  jQuery(function() {    
      jQuery("div#t2e_dialog").dialog({
       beforeClose: function( event, ui ) {
         jQuery(englishTextId).css({"border-radius" : "3px","background" : "", "color" : ""});
       }
     });   
 });   
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: All that code can be replaced by `prompt('Please enter the English text here')` <- It's like the best answer ever!

Comment: can you provide fiddle???

Comment: I can't get the dialog to display in jsfiddle, the problem is accessing the input data generated by the form in the dialog box. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a example with the keyup event. But you could bind any available events:

```
jQuery("body").on("keyup", "#t2e_w", function() {
  var input_user = jQuery('#t2e_w').val();
  console.log(input_user);
  //reg expression here ...
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j6R22/22/

Comment: The input is being displayed in the console but how to get it in a variable? var user_input = jQuery('#t2e_w').val(); doesn't work.

Comment: this code   jQuery("body").on("keyup", "#t2e_w", function(evnt) {evnt.preventDefault(); console.log("Submited");console.log(jQuery('#t2e_w').val());user_input = jQuery('#t2e_w'); }); produces the expected output in firebug console, i.e. char by char,but does not as far I can see assign the input string to user_input. I've made user_input global to avoid any scope issues. I also tried the submit() method as described in the jQuery API but still could not get the required user_input value.

Comment: Fiddle link was not the good one. I've updated my answer with the good one. I'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve. "input_user" variable is populated with the user input here ; then you can check it against the regex.

Comment: Hi, I've got it going and ticked your answer. thanks